# Python - Clearing Command Prompt From Certain Line?

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

I have a script in python which prints a list of lists like so:

```
list_of_lists = [["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]

def print_lists_of_lists(list_of_lists):
    for list in list_of_lists:
        print()
        for char in list:
            print(char, end = "")
```

Using this function I get an output that looks like this:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

Inputs change the contents of these lists. Each time the user makes an input, I clear the command prompt and then reprint the list. This works fine, but if the user spams the inputs the screen "flickers" due to the print process being unable to keep up with inputs.

My idea for a solution is to go to the specific line in the command prompt where the contents of the list changed...

```
abcd
abcc #So from here down is cleared and reprinted
abcd #because the d at the end of the line changed to a c
```

...clear the screen from that line and then reprint the list from the same line. This way, only part of the screen changes, leading to less flickering.

But I have no idea how to do that. I've tried ansi codes to  move the cursor, looked into curses implementations for windows, but I can't seem to find any way to do this. Any thoughts?

**Edit:** In pseudo code this is what I have:

```
while True:
    clear_screen
    print_screen
    wait_for_keypress
```

So if the user holds down a key, this loop goes incredibly fast, making the screen "flicker".

Comment: What is your target audience? If this is for a game, then bulletproof it as much as possible, because gamers often like to game the game itself. If it's for something more practical, like a business application, then you might not need to guard against intentionally poor input. People trying to get real work done just want to use software that doesn't frustrate them. ...And why is this "flickering" a problem?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The flicker IS the problem I'm addressing here. If the user were to hold down a key, the command prompt clear the screen then reprints it so fast that the screan begins to flicker. I'm trying to figure out how to minimize this.

Comment: Yes; I'm asking why that's a problem. People generally understand that scrolling text at top speed has this result. Does this cause errors, or some other kind of problem? Why do you want to eliminate this behavior?

Comment: The reason I would like to solve the problem is simply because it looks bad and is distracting.

Comment: I guess you could jam a `time.sleep(0.5)` into that `while` loop, but I still don't understand why this is so bad. It's very commonly known that fast input, processed quickly, makes for fast output (much better than the alternative: a slow, unresponsive program), and I don't think anyone else cares in the slightest. In other words, it's perfectly normal.

Comment: I'll try a time.sleep, that's actually a pretty good idea.

Comment: Just keep in mind that adding unnecessary delays to the user interface can be a very frustrating experience. Users might prefer the version that feels faster for 99% of their common use cases but looks weird if they feed it bad input on purpose over the version that runs slower 99% of the time but looks okay if they try to feed it bad input.

Comment: Still looks a little wonky... Do you know of any libraries that would let me move individual characters around? Like, if I had a grid with and @ on it, and I wanted to move it up one line. That may solve my problem.

Comment: [50% of the crashes are caused by 1% of the bugs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/04/10045651.aspx). This is one "bug" that won't be causing any crashes, will look perfectly fine to users, and will probably take a ton of work to "fix." If it's that important to you, it's your choice, but be warned that the ROI here is basically zero.

Comment: Learning the Windows console API to accomplish this may be a lot of work for very little gain. An alternative is to use a module that provides a layer of abstraction over the console API, such as [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) for ANSI escape sequences or [curses](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) (read [Curses Programming](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html)).